# Set specific length for each string

Tags: c#

I dont know if there is aleady a fuction which is doing this:
I need to keep specific lenght for my string 20 characters. if my string is 5 characters then to keep rest 15 empty bytes to be null spaces in front of it.
Example

```
string test=12345;
string finalstring =test;
```

output

```
finalstring=               12345;
```

or

```
string test=13 characters;
string finalstring =       13 characters;
```

I cant specify it better.

Comment: [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "I cant specify it better" - using real code that would compile would be helpful. You can't assign 12345 to a string variable, for example. While in this case a [mcve] could be over the top, making the snippets real code would be helpful.

Comment: Did you do anything to find an answer or did you dump the 'problem' here without any 'research effort'..? It was the [2nd hit](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+Set+specific+length+for+each+string&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)
 before you asked..

Comment: @DaisyShipton what about ```12345.ToString()``` lol... I know bad humor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.PadLeft` method. Follow the instructions at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string test="12345";
string finalstring = test.PadLeft(20, ' ');
```

Comment: Thank you padding was what i need

Comment: `12345` is not a string

Answer (score 4):

You can't specify the length of a string in C#.  In C# strings are immutable, meaning they can't change once they are initialized and although they are reference type they work much like value types do in a sense that they grow and shrink via formatting etc.  In other words, every string instance in C# is the length and final length it will ever be and that can't change.  The reference to the string can change, which may be a format of other strings.  Take this for example:

```
var Name = string.empty;
```

Here `Name` is an immutable string of 0 characters and is empty.

```
Name = Name + "Michael";
```

Here `Name` combines the immutable empty string with the immutable "Michael" string and reassigns the `Name` reference to the new value immutable string value of "Michael".  So yes, in this instance, there are 3 strings added to the heap now.  This is why formatting strings in C# can be very resource intensive.

However; there is a `StringBuilder` class which handles this work for you.  It allows you to pass in strings and or characters and build an array of characters internally, that can be then translated to a string at the end.

```
var nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
nameBuilder.Append("Michael");
```

Now there is only, so far, one immutable string of "Michael" that was used and added to `nameBuilder`.  This in turn can be passed around and manipulated without pushing and popping numerous strings to the heap.  This is all a lot but here's you're answer.

In order to specify the length of a string you need to either, work in character arrays or borrow the well adopted `StringBuilder`.  With `StringBuilder` you can specify the size and max size of the string, work with it in a more string like fashion, and benefit from better use of resources.

```
var initialCapacity = 20;
var maxCapacity = 20;
var nameBuilder = new StringBuilder(initialCapacity, maxCapacity);
```

When you're done with `StringBuilder` you can get the produced string by calling the overridden `ToString()` method supplied with it.

Hopefully this helps you understand a little bit more about how it works and why you can't set a size for string.  Some languages, like C++, have string objects that let you set the max capacity but they are simply an array of characters with built in features.  Immutable strings are better for performance but not formatting them in a reasonable way can make them worse; so it's a win / win if you know what you're doing and a lose / lose if you don't.